# Why my model do not accept my dataframe in pipeline in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, machine-learning

I am new in spark and I would like to apply ML on my data in order to predict a value. My propose in the code is predicting the number of connections in my data. Here is my raw data:

```
05:49:56.604899 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 10202: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [.], seq 3641977583:3641987719, ack 129899328, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 10136
05:49:56.604908 00:00:00:00:00:03 > 00:00:00:00:00:02, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 66: 10.0.0.3.5001 > 10.0.0.2.54880: Flags [.], ack 10136, win 153, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432623], length 0
05:49:56.604900 00:00:00:00:00:02 > 00:00:00:00:00:03, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 4410: 10.0.0.2.54880 > 10.0.0.3.5001: Flags [P.], seq 10136:14480, ack 1, win 58, options [nop,nop,TS val 432623 ecr 432619], length 4344
```

I could extract the IP sender and IP receiver within number of their repetitions. Also I could put them into a dataframe. Here is my code:

```
 val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////make train dataframe
    val Dstream_Train = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test/trace1.txt")
    val Row_Dstream_Train = Dstream_Train.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })
    val dataFrame_Train = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema).toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever")
    dataFrame_Train.show()
    dataFrame_Train.groupBy("ip_sender", "ip_reciever").count().toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever", "number_of_conncection").show()
```

My problem is in machine learning part. The main problem is that
`val model = pipeline.fit(dataFrame_Train)` and `model.transform(dataFrame_Test)` do not accept my dataframe and shows me an error. The error is: `Cannot resolve reference fit with such signature`
[image]

Can any body helps me to solve this error. Did I miss something? Here is my complete code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

import scala.util.Try

object Main_ML_with_Streaming {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("saeed_test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    // val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("saeed_test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val session = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local[*]")
      .appName("maasg_test")
      .getOrCreate()


    val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("column0", StringType, true),
      StructField("column1", StringType, true),
      StructField("column2", StringType, true)))
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////make train dataframe
    val Dstream_Train = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test/trace1.txt")
    val Row_Dstream_Train = Dstream_Train.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })
    val dataFrame_Train = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema).toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever")
    dataFrame_Train.show()
    dataFrame_Train.groupBy("ip_sender", "ip_reciever").count().toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever", "number_of_conncection").show()


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////make test dataframe
    val Dstream_Test = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/Test/trace0.txt")
    val Row_Dstream_Test = Dstream_Test.map(line => line.split(">")).map(array => {
      val first = Try(array(0).trim.split(" ")(0)) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array(1).trim.split(" ")(6)) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array(2).trim.split(" ")(0).replace(":", "")) getOrElse ""
      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })
    val dataFrame_Test = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Test, customSchema).toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever")
    dataFrame_Test.show()
    dataFrame_Test.groupBy("ip_sender", "ip_reciever").count().toDF("ip_sender", "ip_reciever", "number_of_conncection").show()


    // Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
      .setInputCol("number_of_conncection")
      .setOutputCol("output")

    val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
      .setNumFeatures(1000)
      .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
      .setOutputCol("features")

    val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.001)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    val model = pipeline.fit(dataFrame_Train)

    // Make predictions on test documents.
    model.transform(dataFrame_Test)
      .select("ip_sender", "ip_reciever", "number_of_conncection", "probability", "prediction")
      .collect()
      .foreach { case Row(ip_sender: String, number_of_conncection: Long, prob: Vector, prediction: Double) =>
        println(s"($ip_sender, $number_of_conncection) --> prob=$prob, prediction=$prediction")

        print("Here is the anwser: *****########*********#########*******")

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error ? can you update your question with that please ?

Comment: @eliasah: Thanks for your response. I have updated the question.

Comment: @eliasah: I should mention that, I saw also a new error. **(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "number_of_conncection" does not exist at ... . However this last error is becuse of bad selection of columns, if you run the code on your machine please ignore that. (I will solve it bymyself)

Comment: If you look at the group by action that you are performing, that column doesn't exist...

Comment: @eliasah: Yes but the problem is on this code: val model = pipeline.fit(dataFrame_Train). Please check the picture of error in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is dirty. I'm not going to debug every line of it. Please create an MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so I can try to help !

Comment: @eliasah: sorry about that. I will update it very soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146066/discussion-between-saeed-talaee-and-eliasah).